# How to stretch first column to fill the screen in android tablelayout?

Tags: android, tablelayout

In my android app, I have a table layout of 2 columns.

I want to stretch the first column width to fill the screen as much as possible. However in this code, it just wraps the width as much as possible...

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Thanks

```
    TableLayout mytable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.studentContainer);

    TableRow tablerow = new TableRow(this);
    tablerow.setOrientation(TableRow.VERTICAL);
    EditText g = new EditText(this);
    g.setText("AAAAA");
    g.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    EditText g2 = new EditText(this);
    g2.setText("BBBBB");
    g2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tablerow.addView(g);
    tablerow.addView(g2);
    mytable.addView(tablerow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TableRow tablerow2 = new TableRow(this);
    tablerow2.setOrientation(TableRow.VERTICAL);
    EditText g4 = new EditText(this);
    g4.setText("AAAAA");
    g4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    EditText g5 = new EditText(this);
    g5.setText("BBBBB");
    g5.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tablerow2.addView(g4);
    tablerow2.addView(g5);
    mytable.addView(tablerow2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

XML

```
            <TableLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="0"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/studentContainer" >
            </TableLayout >
```

Comment: Try setting LayoutParams for table row rather than EditText

Comment: I am already setting it for tablerow.

Comment: Try android:stretchColumns="*"

Comment: What I see is you are creating only one column. Because Table row's orientation is Vertical. So EdiText is coming below the first edit text

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

In `table layout`

```
  TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

and for `table row`

```
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
```

this will make `table row` to fill its `parent` `table layout`

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to stretch the first column width to fill the screen
```

If using view through xml

Use `android:layout_span="2"` so that it will take the width to fill the screen. It depend upon how many column. So it may be max no of column to fill the screen i.e Fill_Parent

```
If you are setting layout_span through code
```

Use like

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams)editText.getLayoutParams();
params.span = toSpan; say 2,3
editText.setLayoutParams(params);
```